# Replacing nth item of a list in scheme

Tags: list, scheme

My code looks like this:

```
    (define replaceNth
      (lambda (nth item list1)
        (cond [(and (= nth 1) (eqv? (pair? list1) #f)) (cons item (cdr list1))] ;; If nth = 1 and there is more to the list, replace element at that location and add rest of list
              [(= nth 1) item] ;; if nth = 1 and there is no more list to add after, return item
              [else (list (car list1) 'derp (replaceNth (- nth 1) item (cdr (list list1))))]))) ;else decrement nth, and traverse rest of list
```

But when i call this on something like this:

```
    > (replaceNth 2 'q (list 'a 'b))
```

The result should be:

```
    (a b)
```

Instead I get an error about passing in something that isn't a pair into the first condition, even though I have an and statement at the beginning checking to see if it was a pair.

```
cdr: contract violation
expected: pair?
given: ()
```

I think i may be missing a statement or wrote a statement wrong.

*Edit: I originally had my code like this:

```
(define replaceNth
  (lambda (nth item list1)
    (cond [(= nth 1) (cons item (cdr list1))] ;; If nth = 1 replace element at that location and add rest of list
          [else (list (car list1) (replaceNth (- nth 1) item (cdr (list list1))))]))) ;else decrement nth, and cons/ recursively call replaceNth on rest of list
```

But i still get the same error, which i dont understand because, when i type this:

```
> (cons 'derp (cdr (cdr (list 'a 'b))))
```

I get this:

```
> (derp)
```

Which means that it shouldnt have a problem when i do something similar in my above code.

Comment: I want to add that im only inputting lists with something in them into this function, im ignoring the case were i pass in an empty list.

Comment: Just because you don't explicitly pass an empty list doesn't mean that such a call can't get generated by the recursion, which is why you need to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function must *always* return a list.

Your middle condition does not return a list; it returns the replacement value.  I believe you want to be returning `list1`, as your first case handles where your counter says to replace the head of the list and there is a head to be replaced, so the second case is where there is no head to be replaced.

Comment: The middle statement is saying that, if there is only one element in the list (ie were at the last element), then return the element we want to replace, because that would be the case where i replace the last value of the list with the element i want there, correct?

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, this is my final code:

```
(define replaceNth
  (lambda (nth item list1)
    (cond [(= nth 1) (cons item (cdr list1))] ;; If nth = 1 replace element at that location and add rest of list
          [else (cons (car list1) (replaceNth (- nth 1) item (cdr list1)))]))) ;else decrement nth, and cons/ recursively call replaceNth on rest of list
```

Input:

```
(replaceNth 2 'q (list 'a 'b))
```

Output:

```
(a q)
```